# BindingException при интеграции MyBatis в Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

Ошибка в сервлете:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement
> (not found): by.gsu.epamlab.mapper.IUserMapper.getUser
>
> exception org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
> processing failed;
>
> nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement
> (not found): by.gsu.epamlab.mapper.IUserMapper.getUser...
>
> root cause org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement
> (not found): by.gsu.epamlab.mapper.IUserMapper.getUser

Сервлет:

```
@Controller
public class MyFirstController {
@Autowired
    private IUserMapper userMapper;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView execute(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", userMapper.getUser(1));//ОШИБКА ТУТ
        return new ModelAndView("start");
    }

}
```

Интерфейс маппера:

```
public interface IUserMapper {

    User getUser(int userId);

}
```

IUserMapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="by.gsu.epamlab.mapper.IUserMapper">
    <sql id="userColumns">user_id as userID, first_name as firstName, last_name as lastName, email_address as emailAddress, role_id as role, password as password</sql>
    <select id="getUser" parameterType="int" resultType="User">
        select <include refid="userColumns"/> from user where user_id = 1
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Бины в настройках:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="by.gsu.epamlab.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="by.gsu.epamlab.service" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/MySQLconnectionDB.properties" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${draft.db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${draft.db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${draft.db.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${draft.db.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="by.gsu.epamlab.entity" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:by/gsu/epamlab/mapper/*.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="by.gsu.epamlab.mapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так? Спасибо.

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта:]

Дополнение к структуре проекта:
[image: доп к структуре]

Comment: Покажите структуру проекта. Где мапперы и .xml для них?

Comment: IUserMapper.xml лежит в resources?

Comment: <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:by/gsu/epamlab/mapper/*.xml" />
Вот тут прописан путь к мапперам. Добавила структуру проекта

Answer (score 0):

`IUserMapper.xml` и все остальные `*.xml` должны быть расположены в `resources`. Структура в ней должна быть такой:

```
-src
  -main
   -java
   -resources
     -by
       -gsu
         -epamlab
           -mapper
             -IUserMapper.xml
             -*.xml
```

Она у Вас есть, но не вижу, что в ней, т.к. на скриншоте она не раскрыта.

Comment: перенесла в ресурсы, ошибка та же, в этом случае mapperLocations по другому прописывается? скрин приложила

Comment: `mapperLocations` прописан правильно. Попробуйте сделать clean и rebuild. И добавьте `<context:component-scan base-package="by.gsu.epamlab.mapper" />` или проще один `<context:component-scan base-package="by.gsu.epamlab" />`

Comment: пока ничего не помогает, еще варианты есть? может ли быть ошибка в самом маппере?

Comment: все правильно сейчас у Вас. Как создавали папку в ресурсах? Просто прописали все с точками? Это вложенные папки, как у вас пакеты в `java`. Уберите галочку `Compact Empty Middle Packages` в `Project Editor` и сделайте папки вложенными. Обновил ответ, чтобы было нагляднее.

Comment: Ошибка и все тут, попробую логику описать, может, что не так понимаю:
1) захожу на страницу http://localhost:8080/start
2) благодаря строке <context:component-scan base-package="by.gsu.epamlab" />
он находит в сервлете MyFirstController метод, в аннотации которого  стоит @RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.GET) и соответственно этот метод выполняется
3) В этом сервлете заинжектила
@Autowired
    private IUserMapper userMapper;
4) при вызове userMapper.getUser(1) он находит xml c помощью бинов SqlSessionFactoryBean и MapperScannerConfigurer

Comment: а еще в самой xml прописываем <mapper namespace="by.gsu.epamlab.mapper.IUserMapper"> и вот что тут не так? настройка бинов?

Comment: Все правильно. Проблема в том, что `mybatis` не находит `*.xml`. Причем не только `mybatis`, но и сама `IDE`, т.к. она вам подсвечивает красным `*.xml` в `mapperLocations`

Comment: <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:/by/gsu/epamlab/mapper/*.xml" />
уже ничего не подсвечивает)

Comment: тогда все должно работать, попробуйте полностью удалить папку `build` в проекте, вручную удалите задеплоенный `.war` с сервера и заново сделайте `build -> deploy`

Comment: Похоже проблема именно в deploy, в варнике отсутствуют файлы *.xml